# Full screen with gnome-player and VLC not working properly

Tags: lubuntu, dell, vlc, fullscreen

I've got this problem since the very first minute I installed Lubuntu from scratch. Full screen mode is not working properly in both gnome-player and VLC:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I fix this?

I'm on a mini Dell Inspiron 1210, graphic card:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) Graphics Controller (rev 07)
```

Comment: I fail to see the significance of that image.

Comment: It's a full screen not showing full screen, just one small freeze image and a small video image :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the solution in the Ubuntu forum http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2121224 So easy as changing the gnome-player video output options until it works. I've changed it to x11 and know it's working :)

Comment: it didn't fixed it for me :( I've tried each output mode. x11 behave like the default one, and almost any other won't play the video properly.

Comment: Any advice on what I should try ?